# Экранирование символа в CSS

Tags: css3

Подскажите, ребят, как быть. В хроме отлично отрабатывает, а мозила не подгружает изображение,присмотрелся в код, в общем прилагаю скрин...
П.С. Между слешем и "р" - курсор

[image: скрин кода]

Comment: вы экранируете символ `p`?

Comment: Лучше вставлять код в виде текста, а не изображения.

Answer (score 2):

Бекслеш(`\`) в CSS - как-раз и есть символ экранирования для url. Если вы ходите экранировать сам бекслеш, вам достаточно продублировать его(`\\`).

Но если бекслеш в вашей строке - разделитель папок, а вовсе не требуемый спецсимвол, то указываете вы путь некорректно - его желательно заменить на обычный прямой слеш(`/`).

Comment: спасибо, но обычный прямой слеш не исправил ситуацию

Answer (score 1):

Просто поставь прямой слеш вместо обратного:

```
url('images/ph.jpg')
```

Comment: не решает проблему